# Congruence proof of modulus equivalence

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I would like some advice if I have approached this problem correctly please:

> let $a,b,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m,n > 0$. Prove that **if** $a\equiv b \pmod n$ and $m|n$, then $a\equiv b\pmod m$

Proof:

Assume $a\equiv b \pmod n$ and $m|n$, then by definition:

$$n=lm \tag{$l\in \mathbb{Z}$}$$
and
$$ a-b=kn\tag{$k\in \mathbb{Z}$}$$

$$\therefore a-b=m(lk)$$
Without loss of generality let 
$$p = lk\tag{$p\in \mathbb{Z}$}$$
$$\therefore a-b=mp$$
Therefore $m|(a-b)$ and so $a\equiv b\pmod m$.
Hence Proof.

Comment: Yes, that looks fine to me.

Comment: Except that the formulation "Without loss of generality" is stylistically not applicable here

Comment: The "without loss of generality" is somewhat misleading, just say let $p=lk$.  Also should be then $n=lm$ for some $l$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that.